# InAppBrowser not working in ionic 3 PWA (web app) or browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps, inappbrowser

I am using InAppBrowser for payment in my Ionic 3 app. Everything works fine in a real device. But when I run my app in browser, inappbrowser plugin doesn't work.
On the ionic platform website  it is clearly written that this plugin supports browser, but using event listeners throws errors like 
 subscribe is not a function and link gets opened in the new tab of standard browser.
Please help me with that.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)